# 20.04 LTS won't boot: systemd-logind.service failed to connect stdout to the journal socket and lots of failures during boot

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, services

Luckily, I have a snapshot of ny Ubuntu 20.04 server because when I reboot it, during bootI see many services failing and then in hangs on systemd-logind.service failed to connect stdout to the journal socket.

**Errors During boot:**

[image]

**Hung here after boot:**

[image]

If I roll back to the snapshot (to before reboot and it's still working):

**Syslog shows:**

```
Feb 01 16:46:31 socwk multipathd[748]: sda: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Feb 01 16:46:31 socwk multipathd[748]: sda: failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument
Feb 01 16:46:31 socwk multipathd[748]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or directory
```

**systemctl gives:**

```
● fwupd-refresh.service                                                                            loaded failed failed    Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd  
systemd-hostnamed.service                                                                        loaded failed failed    Hostname Service
```

If I try to install updates before I reboot, I get the following errors:

```
Installing new version of config file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf ...
Job for systemd-networkd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status systemd-networkd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Job for systemd-resolved.service failed.
See "systemctl status systemd-resolved.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Job for systemd-journald.service failed.
See "systemctl status systemd-journald.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Setting up netplan.io (0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2) ...
Setting up systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Job for systemd-timesyncd.service failed.
```

and:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 mdadm
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 ubuntu-minimal
```

I really don't know where to begin trying to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be caused by the root directory / suffering a change of ownership or permissions. It should normally (under Ubuntu, at least) be owned by root:root with 755 permissions. If this is wrong you can change it with

```
chown root:root / && chmod 755 /
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Wow, lifesaver for such an inscrutable issue, thanks!  Can you elaborate on *how* you figured this out?  Or anyone else for that matter.  Ditto for why this causes these issues?